# How do you get the raw value from a Decodable enum?

Tags: swift, codable

I'm decoding JSON, and one of my values can either be an `Int` or a `String`. I found this code online (and edited it) for how to make it so it can be either an int or a string:

```swift
enum StrOrInt: Decodable {
    
    case int(Int), string(String)
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        if let int = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Int.self) {
            self = .int(int)
            return
        }
        
        if let string = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(string)
            return
        }
        
        throw sot.missingValue
    }
    
    enum sot: Error {
        case missingValue
    }
}
```

This code works, but say it was decoding a string `"test string"`. I would expect the results to be `"test string"`, but instead the results are `string("test string")`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your title is wrong. There are no "raw values" in this story. And that actually makes sense, since you can't set a raw value as if it were a variable. What you've found is an enum that has cases with associated values.

Second, your expectations are wrong. If we decode a string into your enum, what you have is still not a string; it's an enum with a string associated value.

So maybe the problem is merely that you don't understand how to *extract* the string or the int, i.e. how to pull out an associated value. The answer is: use an `if case let` statement.

So, if you've decoded into your enum and it is called `si`:

```
    if case StrOrInt.string( let s ) = si {
        // if we get here, `si` was holding a string
        // and `s` is now that string
        print(s)
    }
```

That will print the value held by the `.string` case, if this *is* the string case.

[By the way: this is almost exactly how Optionals work. `Optional("hello")` is actually an enum case with an associated value, `Optional.some("hello")`. Just thought you'd like to know.]

Comment: I also want to be able to check if it is a .int or a .string

Comment: First of all, that is not what you asked. Second, that's what this code does! You simply write the parallel code for the `.int` case and now both possibilities are covered. Or combine them both into a `switch`. — Besides, if it's not a string it's an int, so the code I gave you actually does answer that question too, doesn't it?